# Does Laravel automatically process the Accept Headers such that it chooses the best route to match the response format if there are multiple?

Tags: php, json, laravel, http-accept-header

I was doing some testing and debugging and ran into an 'observation' that I was sort of unaware of.

The observation was that the Laravel framework intelligently chooses the 'proper' route if I have multiple handlers for the same route, one of which returns one data format, and the other one that return another data format, json and xml in my case.

That is dependent upon what is in the Accept headers in the request, but Laravel apparently handles that transparently ?

I 'cheated' to find out why afterwards by asking ChatGPT to explain how that works, and this is what is said:

Prompt:

```
So if I have 2 requests like this:

curl -X POST  https://example.com/api/path -H 'Authorization:Bearer apikey' -H 'Accept:application/json'  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}'
curl -X POST  https://example.com/api/path -H 'Authorization:Bearer apikey' -H 'Accept:application/xml'  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}'

and also have 2 handlers for the same route in my api.php routes file, one that returns xml and one that returns json, you are saying that they will "work"
```

Yes, if you have two route handlers defined for the same route in your api.php routes file, one returning JSON and the other returning XML, and you send requests with different Accept headers (application/json and application/xml), Laravel's content negotiation mechanism will determine the preferred content type based on the Accept header in each request.

In the first curl command with the Accept: application/json header, Laravel will match the request to the route handler that returns JSON, and it will generate and return a JSON response.

In the second curl command with the Accept: application/xml header, Laravel will match the request to the route handler that returns XML, and it will generate and return an XML response.

This behavior is possible because Laravel's content negotiation mechanism compares the Accept header of the request with the available response formats defined in the route handlers. It selects the route handler that can provide the requested content type and generates the response accordingly.

So, in the scenario you described, Laravel will appropriately handle the requests and return the responses in the corresponding formats based on the Accept headers.

Kind of nice to know, but I presume that is in the documentation ?

[Content Negotiation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#content-negotiation)

Comment: I should mention that that happened while I switching from on format to the other and did not comment out the handler that I had copied from.

Comment: Interesting that there were very few suggested 'Edits" except for the domain name.

Comment: As far as I know you can't automatically route based on `Accepts` headers. That requires knowing the response of each route beforehand, something that is not doable, especially with POST requests which alter your system state. It is most likely something to do with how you've implemented each route

Comment: return response($xml)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

Comment: The route following was the same path, but a different response type, json.  I was just changing the Handler and had not commented out the one I was working from.  I can try to reproduce, but that is a nice feature if it is baked into the Framework.

Comment: echo json_encode($response['appointments']);

That is what the second one was returning, JSON.

Comment: There is no syntax to declare the content type of a route response. The only way Laravel can know what the response content type is, is to run both routes and pick the result from the one that returns the appropriate content type. As I said, Laravel does not do that and for POST requests it would be a mistake to do that, so what you are experiencing is something more of a coincidence. This is not documented behavior and definitely not something you should rely on since the next minor release might see it change.

Comment: The only way Laravel can know what the response content type is, is to run both routes and pick the result from the one that returns the appropriate content type. 

Would there be an "appropriate" way to do that with a different type of request, like a PUT, GET, etc.

Comment: Functionally it is a GET, but I'd rather use JSON for what I am requesting, not a form.

Comment: The reason why I say POST is not safe is due to [indepotence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Idempotent). Again, Laravel does not include this functionality out of the box

Comment: I see.  I'll try changing it to a GET, and then try again.  Can I send JSON using CURL from the CLI with a GET.

curl -X GET 'https://sample.com/api/path?data={"key":"value"}' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer apikey' \
-H 'Accept: application/json'

Comment: The API stuff is kind of fascinating.  Takes awhile to learn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254133/discussion-between-sscotti-and-apokryfos).